# ResponseBody and SessionAttribute incompatible?

Tags: java, spring

I have a method inside a Spring's Controller @ResponseBody and updating Model

```
    @SessionAttribute ("myModel")
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "addPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addImgProvOption(
    @RequestParam("iRow") int iRow,
    @RequestParam("point") String point,
    @RequestParam("size") String size,
    @RequestParam("side") String side,
    @RequestParam("type") String type,
    @RequestParam("percentage") String percentage,
    @ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
    Model model)
    {
      OptionsRow userRow = new OptionsRow (point,size,side, type, 25);
      myModel.addOptionsRow (userRow, 0);
      model.addAttribute("myModel", myModel);
      return "addPoint"";
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that myModel doesn't get updated properly if I leave the ResponseBody tag (I need it because the AJAX at the other side waits for an answer), I think because when the @ResponseBody is used, SessionAtributes apparently dont work (therefore my changes are lost). 
When using ResponseBody, after this method a new instance of MyModel is instantiated wherever "myModel" is required.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. 
This problem description and a possible workaround can be found here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?93859-SessionAttributes-not-working-when-used-with-ResponseBody .

I resolved it in another way, removing the ResponseBody and returning a ResponseEntity with the HTTPStatus to ACCEPTED. This way the AJAX client-side is notified successfully.
And now, without ResponseBody, changes in the ModelAttribute are acknowledged therefore future RequestMapping methods will see them as expected.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "addPoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> addImgProvOption(
@RequestParam("iRow") int iRow,
@RequestParam("point") String point,
@RequestParam("size") String size,
@RequestParam("side") String side,
@RequestParam("type") String type,
@RequestParam("percentage") String percentage,
@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel myModel,
Model model)
{
  OptionsRow userRow = new OptionsRow (point,size,side, type, 25);
  myModel.addOptionsRow (userRow, 0);
  return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
}
```

Comment: Furthermore, byte[] in ResponseEntity is mandatory to make this work.